# How to get all values from a worksheet with a filter using gspread python lib?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Here is the way to get all values from a worksheet as a list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()
```

But how to get all values from a worksheet with a filter?

For example, I have **IS_ACTIVE** column in the worksheet. So I need to get values only where **IS_ACTIVE=1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to sort the data after you've scraped the worksheet. It might be a slower approach, but it'll be straight forward at the least.

```
list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()
filtered_list = []
for i in list_of_lists:
    if i[<index of IS_ACTIVE column>] == 1:
        filtered_list.append(i)
```

If you're familiar with functional programming and you want to be fancy you can use the built in filter method with a lambda. [Docs here.](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

```
list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda i: i[<index of IS_ACTIVE column>] == 1, list_of_lists))
```